# Корзина на WordPress без платежной системы

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно нужно сделать функционал добавления товара (записи) в корзину, без оформления заказа. Есть ли какие-то плагины для подобных задач? И если делать без плагинов, в какую сторону смотреть?

Мне на ум приходит только одно: по клику добавления в корзину, забирать в куки id записи, а на странице корзины формировать товара из куки.

Comment: Есть плагин Woocommerce. Обычно ф-циональность корзины реализуется через session, а не через cookie.

Comment: Woocommerce есть, но он слишком перегружен для моей задачи. Мне не нужна вариативность товаров, учет к-ва и тд. Мне нужно просто добавить в корзину и вывести на отдельной странице (корзина) список добавленных товаров.

Comment: Ну используйте сессии или куки/локал сторедж в зависимости от задач

Comment: >Есть ли какие-то плагины для подобных задач? 
Очень сомневаюсь, что кому-то ещё приходило в голову делать корзину без возможности заказа. Это точно не широко востребовано.  Может всё же не корзина нужна? Может что-то типа "избранное"?